# Appending to a list in Scala

Tags: scala

I have no clue why Scala decided to make this such a chore, but I simply want to add an item to a list

```
var previousIds: List[String] = List()
```

I have tried the following:

```
previousIds ::: List(dataListItem.id)
previousIds :: List(dataListItem.id)
previousIds :+ List(dataListItem.id)
previousIds +: List(dataListItem.id)
previousIds :+ dataListItem.id
previousIds +: dataListItem.id
```

In every one of these instances, the line will run but the list still will contain 0 items

When I try to add a new list:

```
val list = List[String](dataListItem.id)
previousIds += list
```

I get an error that list needs to be a string. When I add a string

```
previousIds += dataListItem.id
```

I get an error that it needs to be a list

For some reason, the only thing that will work is the following:

```
previousIds :::= List[String](dataListItem.id)
```

which seems really excessive, since, adding to a list should be a trivial option. I have no idea why nothing else works though.

How do you add an item to a list in scala (that already exists) without having to make a new list like I am doing?

Comment: I would assume you need mutable list

Comment: Please dig around documentation first: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/concrete-mutable-collection-classes.html

Comment: It is "such a chore" because Scala makes a marked distinction between what is mutable (discouraged) and what is immutable (preferred).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next code should help you for a start.
My assumption you are dealing with mutable collections:

```
val buf = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.empty[String]

buf += "test"

buf.toList
```

In case you are dealing with immutable collections next approach would help:

```
val previousIds = List[String]("A", "TestB")

val newList = previousIds :: List("TestB")
```

Please refer to documentation for mode details:

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html

Answer (score 1):

Use [MutableList](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/collection/mutable/MutableList.html)

```
scala> var a = scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[String]()
a: scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[String] = MutableList()

scala> a += "s"
res0: scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[String] = MutableList(s)

scala> a :+= "s"

scala> a
res1: scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[String] = MutableList(s, s)
```